# Application of the Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability

was revising my stuffs for my stochastics exams and came across this question that I couldn't figure my way around..

---

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with $E(X_1) =a$ and

$$S_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$$

Using the Chebychev inequality, give the smallest possible value of $x$, where $\mathbb{P}(\left | S_{100} - a \right | \geq x) \leq 0.01$, in the case where $X_{1}$ with the parameters  $p \in [0,1]$ is:

a) binomially distributed ($B(10,p)$)

b) geometrically distributed

---

I gathered that $0.01 =\frac{Var(X))}{x^2}$ owing to the Chebychev inequality and figured that if I could derive $Var(X)$, I could then get $x$. And using the given distributions (binomial or geometric), I attempted to solve for $Var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$, although I couldn't proceed any further with the finding of $E(X^2)$.

Although first and foremost, am I heading off into the right track? If so, how should I go about finding $E(X^2)$? Thanks for the help, as always!

Comment: you need to calculate $E(X^2)$ based on underlying distribution of X.  For example for binomial distribution check this link http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Variance_of_Binomial_Distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the right track. Since $S_{n}$ is a sum of iid r.v.s we have

\begin{equation}
\text{E}(S_n) = \frac{1}{n} \text{E}(X_1+\ldots+X_n) =\frac{1}{n}\left[ \text{E}(X_1)+\ldots + \text{E}(X_n) \right] = \text{E}(X_1) = a
\end{equation}
This can be used to relate $a$ to the mean of the distributions you want. Similarly,

\begin{equation}
\text{Var}(S_n) = \text{Var}\left(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n^2} \text{Var}(X_1+\ldots+X_n) = \frac{n}{n^2} \text{Var}(X_1) = \frac{\text{Var}(X_1)}{n}
\end{equation}
This follows since, being iid, the $X_i$ are uncorrelated. Now, noting that $0.01 = 1/n$ the result becomes 
\begin{equation}
x^2 = \text{Var}(X_1)
\end{equation}
Thus,

1) For $X_i \sim Bin(10,p)$, $\text{Var}(X_1) = 10 p(1-p)$

2) For $X_i \sim Geom(p)$, $\text{Var}(X_1) = (1-p)/p^2$